# JOSSO SSO JAVA ASP.NET

Tags: java, single-sign-on, josso

i have 2 applications.first application uses ASP.net other uses java framework.i should implement josso for single sign on for these applications.i dont start this project.What should I do first? can i use one server for these applications?

Answer (score 0):

I search for the same topic and found that JA-SIG CAS may fit your need

[JA-SIG CAS Central Authentication Service](http://www.slideshare.net/craigsdickson/fast-and-free-sso-a-survey-of-open-source-solutions-to-single-sign-on)

1. An open and well-documented protocol
2. A library of clients for Java technology, .NET, PHP, Perl, Apache, uPortal and others